# save a view with NSUserDefaults {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, sdk

i try to use NSUserDefault or something like this , to save a specific view after quit from application and when user lunch application again load from that view ... but i dont know how!

Comment: Serializing an entire UIView class or subclass like this is a brittle design. If it's possible to instead store the various data that makes up the UIView -- strings, numbers, etc. -- you will be better off in the long run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at the [`NSCoder`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) class and its related components. The API is specifically built for arching and dearchiving Objective-C class instances.